# What algorithm could be used to recommend wine given past ratings

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, recommender-system, java, sql

Description: given a user's history of 'likes', I would like to predict what  product should I recommend to the user, based on past likes (content based). The idea is very similar to [Pandora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora_Radio), except that in this case I want to focus on wine (instead of songs).

Here is some example data:

```
 wine name,  color    , price,   Like/dislike
 aaaaa    ,   white   , 200  ,    1
 bbbbb    ,   yellow  , 5    ,    0
 ccccc    ,   white   , 300  ,    1
 ddddd    ,   black   , 100  ,    0
 eeeee    ,   white   , 10   ,    0
```

I would like to recommend to the user a wine that he may like.  For instance I can recommend him an expensive wine with color white and price over 200.

**What algorithm should I use to recommend a certain wine that is based on rating only, like in Pandora?**

In addition, I would like to know what APIs in java, should I use for this system? I would like to emphasis that I'm not looking to create a complex algorithm, I just want to find a similar algorithm, like in Pandora. 
Technology: java, eclipse, mysql, spring framework.

Comment: Your question about the algorithm to use can be answered here. Note however, that asking for an API / code / libraries, etc., is off topic here.

Comment: yes, I'm looking for an algorithm

Comment: you should google recommender systems - there are loads of different algorithms and even a coursera online course

Comment: I obviously googled and researched this subject, But some of those algorithms are truly complex and do not fit my description, this is why I posted this thread